# extract data-img-src from each option of multi select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiple select box with options that contain also a data-img-src attribute. What I would like to do is loop over all the selected options and extract the associated data-img-src attribute. Currently I am doing something like this:

```
$.each($('#imagepicker').val() || [], function(i,value) {
  // this gets me relevant <img> tag but I will still need to parse this
  console.log($('#'+i).context.images[$('#'+i).context.images.length-1].outerHTML);

  // this returns undefined
  console.log($('#'+i).attr('data-img-src'));
}
```

I guess I can parse the outerHTML string that I was able to get, but there must be something easier. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: can you please show some html to us

Comment: I see that because my each already filtered out only the value, I wasn't able to access it. Thank you guys for the responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var all_images = [];
$("#imagepicker option:selected").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).data('img-src'));
    all_images.push($(this).data('img-src'));
});

// Do with all_images what you like, its an array that contains all the img-src's
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select option:selected').each(function(i, value){
    var $img_src = $(this).data('img-src');
    console.log($img_src);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**I think you are using this one : [`imagepicker`](http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/)**

You want to get all selected options and than extract the data attribute:

Try this:

```
$('select option:selected').each(function(i, value){
    var imgsrc = $(this).data('img-src') 
    console.log(imgsrc);
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mgvrc/107/)